# Upgrade 4.5.1 before StartingVertx configuration cluster manager fails

Tags: vert.x

In version 4.4.6, the cluster manager was configured in the beforeStartingVertx phase. How should the latest version 4.5.1 be configured now?

On the latest version, clusters can continue to be deployed through MainLaunch:

```java
@Override
    public void beforeStartingVertx(VertxOptions vertxOptions) {
        vertxOptions.setPreferNativeTransport(true);
        final Config config = ConfigUtil.loadConfig();
        final NetworkConfig networkConfig = config.getNetworkConfig();
        final JoinConfig joinConfig = networkConfig.getJoin();
        final TcpIpConfig tcpIpConfig = joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig();
        tcpIpConfig.setEnabled(true);
        tcpIpConfig.setMembers(Arrays.asList(CLUSTER_IPS));
        final ClusterManager mgr = new HazelcastClusterManager(config);
        vertxOptions.setClusterManager(mgr);
        final EventBusOptions eventBusOptions = vertxOptions.getEventBusOptions();
        eventBusOptions.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 5);
        eventBusOptions.setClusterPingInterval(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));
        eventBusOptions.setClusterPingReplyInterval(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));
        vertxOptions.setEventBusOptions(eventBusOptions);
        if (StrUtil.isBlank(VertxLoadConfig.active)) {
            VertxLoadConfig.active = EnvEnum.PROD.getValue();
        }
    }
```